# Plink is not returning to command prompt when executing start_http

Tags: perl, putty, plink, siebel

I'm executing a command using Plink through a Perl file from a Windows machine.

```
system("cmd /c c:\\plink.exe -batch -ssh -l $user_name @ $host_name  -pw  $pwd start_http");
```

Execution is hanging. When I execute the same command from command prompt, Plink is not returning to command prompt.

Tried using `&` at the end of the command but no use. And I don't want to redirect output to any log file.

Whereas "stop" command is working fine

```
system("cmd /c c:\\plink.exe -batch -ssh -l $user_name @ $host_name  -pw  $pwd stop_http");
```

Comment: What is `start_http` and does it return to shell prompt when you execute it in an SSH terminal?

Answer (score 1):

`stdout/err` must be detached from the terminal.

So change command to

```
system("cmd /c c:\\plink.exe -batch -ssh -l $user_name @ $host_name  -pw  $pwd start_http /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```